# all substrings of a string in java

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=s1.length()-i;j++)
    {
        arr[k]=s1.substring(i,j+i);

        k++;
    }

}
k--;
```

How to find all possible substrings of a string in Java?.For example I have a string say "abc" then i want to generate all possible substrings of abc that is:-"a","b","c","ab","bc","ac","abc".The above code generates all possible substrings except "ac".Can anyone give the code?

Comment: "ac" is not a substring of "abc"

Comment: why "ac" is not a substring of "abc"?

Comment: Well what call to `"abc".substring(...)` would create it? What do you think `"abc".indexOf("ac")` would return?

Comment: unless what you want is all combinations of the characters in the string in the forward order. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FindAllSubStrings {

public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str = "abcdef";
    findSubString(str);
}

public static void findSubString(String str)
{

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        list.add(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
    }

        String temp ="";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            temp ="";
            for(int j=i+1; j<str.length();j++)
            {

                temp = temp +Character.toString(str.charAt(j)) ;
                list.add(Character.toString(str.charAt(i))+temp);
            }

        }
    printAll();
}


public static void printAll()
{
    for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("substrings are "+list.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Answer As per the question **The above code generates all possible substrings except "ac".Can anyone give the code?**

Instead of word **substring** it should be all **combinations**

Following example will give all possible combinations of string:

```
 public class StringCombinations
{
    private StringBuilder   output  = new StringBuilder();
    private final String    inputstring;

    public StringCombinations(final String str)
    {
        inputstring = str;
        System.out.println("The input string  is  : " + inputstring);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StringCombinations combobj = new StringCombinations("abc");
        System.out.println("All possible combinations are :  ");
        combobj.combine();
    }

    public void combine()
    {
        combine(0);
    }

    private void combine(int start)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < inputstring.length(); ++i)
        {
            output.append(inputstring.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(output);
            if (i < inputstring.length())
                combine(i + 1);
            output.setLength(output.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is : ** The above code generates all possible substrings except "ac".Can anyone give the code? ** The above code generates exact output which he wants.. why down vote can anybody tell me please.

Answer (score -1):

This will help, iterate `i` as begin of the substring, and `j` as the end of the substring.

```
String s1 = "abcdefg";
for (int i = 0;i < s1.length - 1;i ++) {
    for (int j = i + 1;j < s1.length;j ++) {
        arr[k ++] = s1.substring(i, j);
    }
}
```